# Log4Net in C# DLL can't load configuration

Tags: c#, .net, dll, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a very basic Log4Net config file to use with my C# DLL. The logging works fine if I create an executable instead of DLL to test in standalone mode, and it has worked fine with exe's in the past as well. But when I switch to DLL mode (Class Library) to work with the other app, the DLL just won't log. Instead when it loads the config file (XmlConfigurator.Configure(file)) I see the error-
"you have tried to set a null level to root"

**Config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="Full" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
  <file value="log/eft.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
  <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="[%d] %-5p (%logger{1}:%line) - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

I have tried setting the log config through code as well, even that didn't work. I didn't get any error with that, but it still didn't log. I have all the permissions to create/write to files since I am logged in as admin.

Using code instead of config file-

```
       Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
       hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders(); 
       hierarchy.Root.Level = log4net.Core.Level.All;
       hierarchy.Configured = true;

       FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
       fileAppender.AppendToFile = true;
       fileAppender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
       fileAppender.File = "log.txt";
       PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout();
       pl.ConversionPattern = "%d [%2%t] %-5p [%-10c]   %m%n%n";
       pl.ActivateOptions();
       fileAppender.Layout = pl;
       fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
       log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: What process is hosting your dll? The log4net configuration needs to be in the configuration file for that process.

Comment: There is a third party application that is talking to a DLL written in C++, which in turns calls my DLL that is written in C#. I have only written the one in C# and can't touch the other two.

Comment: _you have tried to set a null level to root_ - `<level value="Full" />` - there is no level called `Full`. Use `All` instead.

Comment: Weird, Full worked when used with the executable. But yes you are right, it should be All. Switched it to All and that null level to root is gone. But I still don't see anything being logged, no Log4net related errors either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the third party application is called ThirdPartyApp.exe, and this is hosting your dll, you need to create a ThirdPartyApp.exe.config that contains the log4net configuration which you posted.

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same error. After doing the Configure, I tried this-            `bool val = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Configured;` and it returns true. Not sure why the root level is not being set.  Even setting the root level manually doesn't quite help create the log file - `((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)logger.Logger).Level = log4net.Core.Level.All;`